# Append data into data frame

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

they show me these errors `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length` how can I solve these error kindly anyone who give me solution of these problem I am trying many approaches but I can not solve these error so how can I handle these error my array is not same

```
import enum
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd 

url="https://www.fleetpride.com/parts/otr-coiled-air-hose-otr6818"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")
raw_json = ""
for table_index,table in enumerate( soup.find_all("script")):
    if('CCRZ.detailData.jsonProductData = {"' in str(table)):
        x=str(table).split('CCRZ.detailData.jsonProductData = {"')
        raw_json = "{\""+str(x[-1]).split('};')[0]+"}"
        break
           
req_json = json.loads(raw_json)
# with open("text_json.json","w")as file:
#     x=json.dump(req_json,file,indent=4)

temp = req_json

name=[]
specs=[]


title=temp['product']['prodBean']['name']
name.append(title)


item=temp['specifications']['MARKETING']
for i in item:
    try:
        get=i['value']
    except:
        pass

    specs.append(get)


temp={'title':name,'Specification':specs}
df=pd.DataFrame(temp)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*While error is quite clear, question and expected result is not.*

The way you try to create the DataFrame has to deal with missing rows, thats why the error comes up. To fix this you could create DataFrame from dict:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp, orient='index')
```

**But** that looks pretty ugly and could not processed well later on, so an alternative would be:

```
data = [{
    'title':temp['product']['prodBean']['name'],
    'specs':','.join([s.get('value') for s in temp['specifications']['MARKETING']])
}]
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

or following if you like to have each spec in a new row:

```
data = {
    'title':temp['product']['prodBean']['name'],
    'specs':[s.get('value') for s in temp['specifications']['MARKETING']]
}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

###### Example

```
import enum
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd 

url="https://www.fleetpride.com/parts/otr-coiled-air-hose-otr6818"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")
raw_json = ""
for table_index,table in enumerate( soup.find_all("script")):
    if('CCRZ.detailData.jsonProductData = {"' in str(table)):
        x=str(table).split('CCRZ.detailData.jsonProductData = {"')
        raw_json = "{\""+str(x[-1]).split('};')[0]+"}"
        break

temp = json.loads(raw_json)

data = [{
    'title':temp['product']['prodBean']['name'],
    'specs':','.join([s.get('value') for s in temp['specifications']['MARKETING']])
}]

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

|  | title | specs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | OTR Trailer Air Hose and Electric Cable Assembly, 15' | Spiral wound,Includes hang collar,One bundle for easy management |